# find number of anagrams for one array of string in respect to another array of string

Tags: python, arrays, string, anagram

Suppose there are two arrays of strings. One array is named query, and the other one is named dictionary. For each string element of the query, you need to find how many anagrams of it exist among the elements of dictionary and push that number to another array. Your code has to return that array, and its size should be equal to that of the query (as expected).

My approach to solving this problem was:

1. loop through each element of query and dictionary(in a nested loop);
2. check if the length of an element of the query was equal to the nested element of the dictionary. If yes, then I checked they had the same characters using `set(word)==set(st)` (st refers to the dictionary).

My code was like this:

```
anagrams = list()
for word in query:
   ana = 0
   for st in dictionary:
      if(len(word)==len(st)):
          if(set(word)==set(st)):
             ana = ana + 1
   anagrams.append(ana)
```

This logic gives me the correct result, but it is not optimized. As a result, it exceeds the 10-sec time limit. The length of both query and dictionary can be up to 10^15.

My logic runs in O(n^2) time. Is there any way to optimize the code a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python `dict`ionaries to speed things up:

```
dict_sorted = {}

for s in dictionary:  #  linear in terms of the size of `dictionary`
    sorted_s = sorted(s.lower())
    dict_sorted[sorted_s] = dict_sorted.get(sorted_s, 0) + 1

anagrams = []

for s in query:  #  linear in terms of the size of `query`
    sorted_s = sorted(s.lower())
    anagrams.append(dict_sorted.get(sorted_s, 0))
```

Using `collections.Counter` to shorten things:

```
from collections import Counter

dict_sorted = Counter([sorted(s.lower()) for s in dictionary])

anagrams = [ dict_sorted.get(sorted(s.lower()), 0) for s in query ]
```

Comment: I understood the logic using the dictionary part. But I could not get the logic using the collections.

Comment: @lonewolf `collections.Counter` does the job of counting for us, so instead of having to do the counting with our loop, we just give a list and it counts the occurrences of each item.

Answer (score 0):

You logic is incorrect, if you test the character set and length, `abbc` and `aabc` will appear to be anagrams, which they aren't.

Now to have a O(n) time, you can count the characters in each word of the dictionary using `collections.Counter`, and convert to items, then frozenset to be itself hashed in a Counter. Then simply check each word of the query once:

```
from collections import Counter

query = ['aabc', 'xyz', 'opq']
dictionary = ['abac', 'baac', 'xyz', 'jkl', 'yxz']

c = Counter(frozenset(Counter(w).items()) for w in dictionary)
anagrams = [c[frozenset(Counter(w).items())] for w in query]
```

output: `[2, 2, 0]`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't get your logic.

Comment: For each word on the dictionary, create a hash. Here I used a counter, transformed to frozenset. And I count how many hashes are similar in the dictionary, making a dictionary of counts for each hash. Then when reading query, I hash reach word and her directly the count from the dictionary of counts, which is O(1).

Comment: @lonewolf I just had a look at the other answer, basically it does the same thing but with a different hashing method, that could be more efficient as sorting can be expensive. Please let me know if you still don't understand.